# Where is this "Business Value - Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 1_0" field name coming from?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

When I create a new Team Project in TFS 2013 from within VS 2013 off of the "Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013" (default) process template, I get a field named:

```
Business Value - Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 1_0
```

In the Product Backlog Item work item type.

If a different user creates a team project (on the same server, using same VS version), it is simply named:

```
Business Value
```

Weird..

The problem with this is that I want to import my work item type, which I have customized by adding new custom fields, into another team project, however I get

```
error importing work item type defintion:
TF26177: The field Microsoft>VSTS.Common.BusinessValue cannot be renamed from 'Business Value - Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 1_0' to 'Business Value'.
```

I am afraid to simply rename this out-of-the-box field name in my WIT - I don't trust this would be okay when it comes time to upgrade TFS again..

Any idea where this "Business Value - Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 1_0" field name is coming from? I don't see this string anywhere in the "Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013" Process Template files when I export/download it from Process Template Manager.

Comment: Are you and the other user using the same collection? Each collection has its own copy of the process template. Check the output of the witadmin listfields command: 'witadmin.exe listfields /collection:"<collection url>" /n:"Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BusinessValue"' What name do you see there?

Comment: We were definitely using the same collection

Comment: Was this server upgraded from the previous version of TFS? Have you ever used "Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 1.0" template for this collection?

Comment: It was upgraded from TFS 2010 to 2013. I have never used that template (I didn't even know it was available in that version)